# How to access to hard disk without sudo permission?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, hard-drive

How to access to hard disk without sudo permission?

My desktop has 1T hard disk. When I installed Ubuntu 14.04, I gave /home almost 500G, and 500G for /data.

How can i write files to the /data without sudo? mount it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change ownership of the /data folder to your user/group using chown like this.

```
xxxubuntu$ sudo chown -R username:group /data
```

Replace username:group with your username and group. The -R is the recursive option and will change ownership of anything under /data.

Next time try AskUbuntu for things like this.

Pat

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER /data`, `$USER` instead of `username:group` should also work